# Dockerfile for shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Dockerfile for a shiny-app. Packages that are being used: shiny, ggplot2. The app (app.R) will be run via a app_run.R file using the following command "Rscript app_run.R"

I have used a rocker container, but I think this has installed all sorts of packages. Does someone know how to build an absolutely basic Dockerfile to run a shinyapp? and are there any obsolete lines in my Dockerfile?

The Dockerfile I have build:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.1
#install necessary libraries
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('ggplot2','shiny'))"
COPY . /usr/local/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/app
CMD ["Rscript","app_run.R"]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Does that Dockerfile not work? What does it do? It looks like it adds ggplot2 and shiny to the base rocker image, copies files from your working dir to /usr/local/src/app, then runs Rscript on app_run.R from there. If that exists, and launches your shiny app, then that should work.

Comment: There's nothing obsolete there. That's about as minimal a Docker file as possible for what you are doing. If you are trying to build a more lightweight *image* then you might want to build from a base Linux image and install R into it and then you can control the packages within. The point of rocker images is partly you get most of a kitchen sink ready to run.

Comment: It all worked. I just think it installed a lot of packages, which I don't need, when I ran the file. Probably, because rocker/r-ver:3.5.1 holds lots of package installations. (I am really new to docker). I was wondering whether I could call sth simpler (maybe not using rocker).

Comment: Thanks. Just out of interest: how would I build a base Linux image?

Comment: If you look at the rocker Dockerfiles you can trace it back to rocker/r-ver image which has "FROM debian:stretch"  - it then adds dependencies and builds R: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-ver/~/dockerfile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one minor problem with your `Dockerfile` from my point of view: On which port will the shiny app be served? By default shiny uses a random port, which isn't really useful when you run a docker container and want to map some individual port from the container to the host. I typically use port `3838` like this:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.1
#install necessary libraries
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('ggplot2','shiny'))" \
 && echo 'options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")' >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site \
 && rm -rf /tmp/*

EXPOSE 3838

COPY . /usr/local/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/app
CMD ["Rscript","app_run.R"]
```

Later I can use

```
docker run -p 3838:3838 <shiny_image>
```

and the app will be available on `http://localhost:3838`.

If you want something smaller, you could use

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
            r-cran-shiny r-cran-ggplot2 \
 && echo 'options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = "0.0.0.0")' >> /etc/R/Rprofile.site \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 3838

COPY . /usr/local/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/app
CMD ["Rscript","app_run.R"]
```

Without all the development packages, that might be smaller.